# PHP Array within array within array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello how do I access the attachments array here, for example how do I return the permalink field:

```
  Array ( [name] => Temp List 
          [attachments] => Array ( 
             [32107] => Array ( 
               [id] => 32107 
               [permalink] => /fred 
               [image] => http://wp-content/uploads/2017/11/f20e4f030a09f2a87740715f15679aa5-3-768x1154.jpg 
               [thumbnail] => http://wp-content/uploads/2017/11/f20e4f030a09f2a87740715f15679aa5-3-200x300.jpg 
               [name] => fred 
               ) 
             ) 
           )
```

I know there are many questions on arrays but I have tried every way and cant seem to get it.

Many thanks

Comment: learn `foreach`

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
   $array['attachments']['32107']['permalink']
```

Comment: @user43251: is this use full??

Comment: No, it's n​o​t.

Comment: @deceze: can you mention what is the issue with above code

Comment: It doesn't work. There's no key `permalink` in the `attachments` array.

Comment: no - how are you returning the permalink ?

Comment: yes it.. i didnot see properly....i'm updating my ans...

Comment: @user43251: updated ans.

Comment: I don't think `32107` will be a constant value known in advance. OP most likely needs a loop here!

Comment: need a loop!! yes you are right

Comment: @user43251 You are aware that your question is closed as a duplicate of a post that explains how to do this in excruciating detail, yes?

Comment: @user43251 i think you need this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well the other topics havent helped me but thanks i guess

Comment: @user43251: is above code use full now??